# Sending a greeting/welcome message from the bot as soon as the Webchat control is loaded

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm developing a bot using Microsoft's Bot framework in C#. I'm trying to send a welcome message to the user as an introduction before he/she sends anything.

After researching, I somewhat achieved this using `HandleSystemMessage` function and sending the message in the case of a `ConversationUpdate` as follows:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate) 
{
    IConversationUpdateActivity update = activity;
    if (update.MembersAdded.Any())
    {
        foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
        {
            if (newMember.Id != activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
                reply.Text("Hello, how can I help you?");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)bubble);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing with this method:

- In the Emulator, the welcome message appears when you hit the refresh button above or when the user starts typing if it has been idle for a while. This is the behavior I'm looking for and it is working as intended.
- Now when using the [Bot Framework Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) component, this message is send when the user initiate the conversation, i.e. when the user types something and sends it to the bot. This is not what I want, but rather, I'd like the message to be shown from the bot as soon as the web chat control is loaded as the message will contain some instructions on how to use the bot.

I assume my problem could be solved using another `ActivityType` perhaps or some Javascript 'hacky' way but I couldn't find a solution up until now.

Comment: Despite your initial comment, this is still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363035/the-second-conversationupdate-event-will-follow-at-the-back-of-user-first-input ;-)

Comment: Well, you're right. I was not searching for the right tags/words this is why this question never came up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the webchat component, you can use the backchannel functionality to send a hidden message to your bot, in order to launch the greetings.

Heere is a sample of the implementation on the webchat side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bot" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Get parameters from query
        const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
        // Language definition
        var chatLocale = params['locale'] || window.navigator.language;

        // Connection settings
        const botConnectionSettings = new BotChat.DirectLine({
            domain: params['domain'],
            secret: 'YOUR_SECRET',
            webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true'
        });

        // Webchat init
        BotChat.App({
            botConnection: botConnectionSettings,
            user: { id: 'userid' },
            bot: { id: 'botid' },
            locale: chatLocale,
            resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById('bot'));

        // Send hidden message to do what you want
        botConnectionSettings.postActivity({
            type: 'event',
            from: { id: 'userid' },
            locale: chatLocale,
            name: 'myCustomEvent',
            value: 'test'
        }).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('event sent'); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On your bot side, you will get this event on your Message Controlelr:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    // DEMO PURPOSE: echo all incoming activities
    Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));

    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
    connector.Conversations.SendToConversation(reply);

    // Process each activity
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    // Webchat: getting an "event" activity for our js code
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && activity.ChannelId == "webchat")
    {
        var receivedEvent = activity.AsEventActivity();

        if ("myCustomEvent".Equals(receivedEvent.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // DO YOUR GREETINGS FROM HERE
        }
    }
    // Sample for Skype: in ContactRelationUpdate event
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate && activity.ChannelId == "skype")
    {
        // DO YOUR GREETINGS FROM HERE
    }
    // Sample for emulator, to debug locales
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && activity.ChannelId == "emulator")
    {
        foreach (var userAdded in activity.MembersAdded)
        {
            if (userAdded.Id == activity.From.Id)
            {
                // DO YOUR GREETINGS FROM HERE
            }
        }
    }

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

I made a working demo using this functionality to send the user locale, it's [here](https://github.com/nrobert/Bot-Language-Demo) on Github

Comment: The demo code on Github is very handy as well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Web chat.

> Using WebChat or directline, the bot's ConversationUpdate is sent when the conversation is created and the user's ConversationUpdate is sent when they first send a message. [[1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/869#issuecomment-387613979)]

A work around would be to send a message to the bot from the web-chat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<script>

    var user = {
        id: 'user-id',
        name: 'user name'
    };

    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        token: '[DirectLineSecretHere]',
        user: user
    });

    BotChat.App({
        user: user,
        botConnection: botConnection,
        bot: { id: 'bot-id', name: 'bot name' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));

    botConnection
        .postActivity({
            from: user,
            name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
            type: 'event',
            value: ''
        })
        .subscribe(function (id) {
            console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
        });
</script>
```

[[2](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4245#issuecomment-369311452)]

I didn't change anything in my bot code to achieve this.