# Globalization and Localization in Botframework web chat

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I am using the BotFramework-WebChat to create a web client for my chat bot.

```
const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
domain: params['domain'],
secret: <secret>,
token: params['t'],
webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true'
});

BotChat.App({
bot: bot,
botConnection: botConnection,
user: user
}, document.getElementById('chatBot'));
```

It works fine but I would like to customize it a bit. For which I can use/override some CSS. However, I do not see any option to support a different locale other than English. I would like something similar to what we have in the BotFramework emulator. However, I don't want to give a UI control for that. Instead, I want to trigger a specific locale from the code within the client side.
[image]

Is there any property or option available to set that?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to send a custom event using backchannel capability. With that, you send a hidden message to your bot to specify the locale you need.

You have an example of this implementation on a previous question I answered:
[Sending a greeting/welcome message from the bot as soon as the Webchat control is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982168/sending-a-greeting-welcome-message-from-the-bot-as-soon-as-the-webchat-control-i/)

Comment: I saw your post. I know we can use the back channel and send any type of details/parameters to the Chatbot API. Depending on that we can use translate logic in the backend. My question is- If this is supported by the directline channel itself. Also, I tried setting `locale: chatLocale` property while initializing the BotChat expecting the UI to atleast change automatically. Guess that's not how it works?

Comment: What value did you put on `chatLocale`?

Comment: I put `fr-CA` and `es-es`. I mean the interface changes but I was thinking if the typed in text and the response also gets translated. May be I am expecting too much :D.

Comment: Yes, you are :D . The locale received on the bot side seems only to be used for Resources like error messages. For the translation, you have to implement the desired behavior