# .NET Core 2.2-How to use backchannel to display bot welcome message before user types in Webchat

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, asp.net-apicontroller, web-chat

I am trying to make my chatbot display the initial welcome message without the user having to type first to initiate conversation in webchat.

I have found this solution of using backchannel: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982168/sending-a-greeting-welcome-message-from-the-bot-as-soon-as-the-webchat-control-i)

but since the ApiController class is deprecated in `.NET core 2.2` I cannot use this solution.

### MessagesController.cs

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController

{ 

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        . . .
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new  Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
        . . .
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
}
```

Because of this, in the above sample code provided in the solution, 'Conversation' and 'Request' do not exist in the current context.
I am looking for a version of the above solution that works with `.NET core 2.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inheriting from ControllerBase and using the ApiController declaration.

```
[ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
```